Using a connection authenticate with OAuth2 token, how can I fix 'Already connected' error when sending request?
In a SpringBoot context, I use WebServiceTemplate to make a SOAP request on various distant resources. Up to now, I was using basic authentication to access those but I've to switch to OAuth2 authentication for one of them.
In a nutshell, I manage to retrieve the OAuth2 token (thanks to an interceptor) and to add it on my request. Then as by the Spring documentation, I try to send my request from the interceptor.
Then I see two different paths but none is currently working. (code extracts can be found at the end of description)

either I try to get an HttpResponse by httpRequest.execute(). This fail with a 405 error. The body of my POST request may be wrong but I'm still pretty sure it's correct. Then, as the messageContext didn't got a response, the WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest of Spring is executed => It get a 504 error (time out without more explanation :-/). Anyhow, this path seem tedious to me, as I don't see a clear way to add the retrieved httpResponse into the messageContext. Hence, I'm afraid Spring will always try to resend the request from WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive as messageContext.hasResponse() keep being false
or I use the HttpUrlConnection connection.send(message) after having retrieve the OAuth2 token and included it in the request. But this seems to fail (without error) and as the messageContext still has not receive a response, the WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive still execute the connection.send(request). This time, I get a, 'Already connected' error. Which seems logical as the connection has already been used in the interceptor (without success)

I have the feeling that 2nd approach is more natural as the 1st one implies to force a HttpResponse into a MessageContext.
But as none of them is working, I must be missing something important, yet maybe trivial.
Maybe the idea of using the interceptor is not so effective ?
I would be truly grateful if anyone could give me an hint of what may be wrong in my approach of this (should be :/) simple task.
Creation of the WebServiceTemplate (in a factory)
WebServiceTemplate initTemplate(Destination destination) {
    WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();

    template.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    template.setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);
    template.setMessageFactory(messageFactory); // messageFactory depends on SOAP version
    template.setMessageSender(messageSender);
    template.setDefaultUri(destination.getUrl());
    template.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[] {new OAuth2WebServiceClientInterceptor(oAuth2TokenInterceptor) });
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}

OAuth2WebServiceClientInterceptor's definition
public OAuth2WebServiceClientInterceptor(ClientHttpRequestInterceptor clientHttpRequestInterceptor) {
    this.clientHttpRequestInterceptor = clientHttpRequestInterceptor;
}

public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {

    HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext().getConnection();
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    try {
        ClientHttpRequest httpRequest = simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(connection.getUri(), HttpMethod.POST);
        // prepare the body to provide it to the intercept method
        AxiomSoapMessage message = (AxiomSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
        Source soapBody = message.getSoapBody().getPayloadSource();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(soapBody, new StreamResult(byteArrayOutputStream));

        byte[] body = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        httpRequest.getBody().write(body);
        ClientHttpResponse response = clientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(httpRequest, body,
                                                                            new ClientHttpRequestExecution() {    
                @Override
                public ClientHttpResponse execute(HttpRequest request, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                    ClientHttpResponse response = httpRequest.execute(); // get 405 error
                    // messageContext.setResponse((AxiomSoapMessage) response); // cast error
                    return response;
                }
        });
        // connection.send(message); // cause an 'Already connected' error in WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false; // the interceptor has failed.
    }    
    return true;
}

oAuth2TokenInterceptor = bean initiated with this interecept method :
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("destinationId")
                                                                    .principal(new AuthenticationPrincipal())
                                                                    .build();
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);

    String token = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    log.debug("token acquired: " + token);

    request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
    return execution.execute(request, body);
}

Spring implementation of WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive:
protected <T> T doSendAndReceive(MessageContext messageContext, WebServiceConnection connection,
            WebServiceMessageCallback requestCallback, WebServiceMessageExtractor<T> responseExtractor) throws IOException {
        int interceptorIndex = -1;
        try {
            if (requestCallback != null) {
                requestCallback.doWithMessage(messageContext.getRequest());
            }
            // Apply handleRequest of registered interceptors
            boolean intercepted = false;
            if (interceptors != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < interceptors.length; i++) {
                    interceptorIndex = i;
                    if (!interceptors[i].handleRequest(messageContext)) {
                        intercepted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // no send/receive if an interceptor has set a response or if the chain
            // has been interrupted
            if (!messageContext.hasResponse() && !intercepted) {
                sendRequest(connection, messageContext.getRequest());
                if (hasError(connection, messageContext.getRequest())) {
                    triggerAfterCompletion(interceptorIndex, messageContext, null);
                    return (T) handleError(connection, messageContext.getRequest());
                }
                WebServiceMessage response = connection.receive(getMessageFactory());
                messageContext.setResponse(response);
            }
            logResponse(messageContext);
            if (messageContext.hasResponse()) {
                if (!hasFault(connection, messageContext.getResponse())) {
                    triggerHandleResponse(interceptorIndex, messageContext);
                    triggerAfterCompletion(interceptorIndex, messageContext, null);
                    return responseExtractor.extractData(messageContext.getResponse());
                } else {
                    triggerHandleFault(interceptorIndex, messageContext);
                    triggerAfterCompletion(interceptorIndex, messageContext, null);
                    return (T) handleFault(connection, messageContext);
                }
            } else {
                triggerAfterCompletion(interceptorIndex, messageContext, null);
                return null;
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
        /*...*/
        }
    }

